# Java IOException during API request to Stripe (APIConnectionException)

Tags: google-app-engine, stripe-payments

The specific action we are trying to performe is to create a charge request with Stripe:

```
Charge charge = Charge.create(params);
```

Using Stripe's Java implementation (version 5.35.1) we encounter a APIConnectionException when running the application on the deployed App Engine server. Interestingly, the issue does not occur using App Engine's local dev server.

We contacted Stripe and they said everything is fine on their side. They explained that "this error indicates that your server is not able to contact our API and that it ends up timing out waiting for an answer. Usually, this is due to something misconfigured on your server such as a DNS not redirecting to Stripe properly."

We were wondering if there are some configuration settings on App Engine which cause the problem. However, since there is no specific error message we cound not figure out what might cause the connection problem.

Similar problems which did not provide enough help to resolve this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/35901039

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have solved itself. It occured for a couple of days and since a few hours the exact same code is working fine. Just like in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35901039 the problem is suddenly gone for some reason.